# how to search backwards the HYPERLINK with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

[tabla de ejemplo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18_QJoEDtkjWVK0qHHBlQH_8LQyZV7aSwSNrgbqmA3MM/edit#gid=0)
"By the way, I have already read everywhere that `arrayformula` does not work with the other functions that I have used and despite that I have tried infinite combinations but I still have hope..."

I need to find a way to replicate something like in the picture, but using `ARRAYFORMULA` because the current form that I discovered and made work stops working if they insert rows as I would need to copy the formulas to the new cells.

[image: sheet example]

For the "Next" hyperlink it is "easy" since I use the following formula, where the 2nd parameter of the `MATCH` function is relative and searches the lower range for the current cell.

Column D:

```
=IF( ISERROR( MATCH( $A2; $A3:$A; 0)); "-"; HYPERLINK( "#gid=772477244&range="&ADDRESS( ROW()+MATCH($A2;$A3:$A;0); 1; 4); "Next"))
```

For the "Previous" hyperlink... well... it's a bit more complicated.
First: I need two auxiliary columns, one to number the rows (with `arrayformula`) and another to get the previous row in which it appears (for this I found 3 different ways: `query()`, `maxif()` or a combination of `max(filter())` although none work for me with `ARRAYFORMULA`).

Column C:

```
=IF(ISERROR(F2);"-"; HYPERLINK("#gid=772477244&range="&ADDRESS(F2;1;4); "Previous"))
```

Column E:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( SI( A:A="";; FILA(A:A)))
```

Column F ( I really don't know which one is the best)

option 1:

```
=QUERY( A:E; "SELECT E WHERE E < "&E2&" AND  A = '"& A2&"' ORDER BY E DESC LIMIT 1")
```

option 2:

```
=MAX( FILTER( E:E; A:A=A2; E:E<E2))
```

option 3:

```
=MAXIFS( $E:$E; $A:$A; $A2; $E:$E; "<"&FILA($E2))
```

**Note:** if you find inconsistencies of `,` and `;` It's because it's in another language.

I hope I was clear and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))+{-1, 1}, {A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), ROW(A2:A)}, 2, )), 
 "---", HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A"&VLOOKUP(A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))+{-1, 1}, {A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), ROW(A2:A)}, 2, ), 
 {"previous", "next"}))))
```

or in your locale:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A))+{-1\ 1}; {A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A))\ ROW(A2:A)}; 2; )); 
 "---"; HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A"&VLOOKUP(A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A))+{-1\ 1}; {A2:A&
 COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A))\ ROW(A2:A)}; 2; ); 
 {"previous"\ "next"}))))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ubqA78VttICelrZgd2tg6QT6wr7QwqhdLYxfyoTouHk/edit#gid=0)

**note: in your real spreadsheet don't forget to change gid if it is different from 0**